# An error does not occur when the event log is acquired, but an error is displayed when the event log is not acquired

Tags: apex

I'm using Apex triggers to rewrite the value of the record.
An error occurs and when I try to get the log, the error stops happening.
I posted this because the log is unknown and it may take some time to resolve the issue.
I would like to know what you think of it.

I am sorry that my English is so bad

Comment: You can avoid the error by adding [system.debug] before the error point, and then add I did.

Comment: Can you please share the relevant code and error message you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm not sure without seeing code, this sounds a lot like this known issue which is (finally) going to be addressed in Summer '20.

[List.contains() fails to detect element match when input param is an SObject Id field; it succeeds when debug logs are enabled](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001RXPlQAO&title=list-contains-fails-to-detect-element-match-when-input-param-is-an-sobject-id-field-it-succeeds-when-debug-logs-are-enabled)

Comment: This seems to be the cause.
Thank you for looking for it.

Thank you.